# How to enable CiviDiscount for members?

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

I'm considering using CiviMember and CiviDiscount to offer discounts to members... but when I try to create a new discount code, there is no member option.  How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 6):

CiviDiscount is smart ... and will only display the membership option if you have created at least one membership type.

So...

1. Create your membership (Administer -> CiviMember -> Membership Types)
2. Create your discount

Note that your discounts can apply to more than one membership!